# How to define a route with optional parameter using reach-router

Tags: react-router, reach-router

I need to define a route that takes in an optional parameter "format". Initially I only defined the route:
`<FleetView path='/fleet/:format' />` but whenever I went to a URL without the format, eg. `localhost:3000/fleet` or `localhost:3000/fleet/` it would give an error. I fixed it by adding an additional redundant route without the format parameter: `<FleetView path='/fleet/' />`. The code that works is reproduced below:

```
const NotFound = (props) => {
    return <Redirect to='/fleet' />;
}
...
<Router >
  <Redirect noThrow from="/" to="/fleet" />
  <FleetView path="/fleet/" />
  <FleetView path="/fleet/:format" />
  <NotFound default />
</Router>;
```

My question is whether or not there's a way to do this without the redundant route, i.e. to make the `:format` parameter optional?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook to match the current URL in the same way a `Route` would, e.g.

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="/" to="/fleet" />
  <Route path="/fleet">
    <Fleet />
  </Route>
  <Route>
    <div>Not found</div>  
  </Route>
</Switch>

...

function Fleet() {
  const match = useRouteMatch("/fleet/:format");
  if (!match) return <div>No format</div>;
  return <div>format = {match.params.format}</div>;
}
```

So the `Switch` has a single route that renders the `Fleet` component for the `/fleet` path, but the `Fleet` component matches against the `/fleet/:format` path to get the `format` param (which might not match)